# Buttons not showing up in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm having a ton of trouble figuring out why the buttons in this won't show? They were showing up earlier today when I test ran the program but now I've been stuck for 2 hours trying to get the buttons to show up again. It's also really weird because the panel is definitely showing up because the phrase "Welcome to the BookListApp" is showing up.

```
    public BookListUI() {
        textPrompt.setText("Welcome to the BookListApp, fellow bookworm. Start storing your books immediately!");
        textPrompt.setBounds(WIDTH / 2 - 300, 50,500,100);
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        panel.add(textPrompt);
        addButtons();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("BookList Application");
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void addButtons() {
        panel.add(new JButton("Finished books"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Favorite books"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Search by genre"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Save all your books!"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Load your BookList Application"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Exit application"));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BookListUI();
    }
```

Comment: The problems start here: `panel.setLayout(null);`. Fix that using layouts before wasting any more of your time or asking us to waste ours.

Comment: General tips: 1) [Edits] to add a [mre]. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of how the GUI is expected to appear at both default size and when made larger. 3) `panel.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT); .. frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);` The best than can be said of this is that the panel size will be ignored. One or both of the sizes is wrong, as a panel cannot be was big as the frame that displays it. It's better to `pack()` a frame to the right size for the content it displays. If the GUI uses layouts, that size will be suggested automatically.  4) `textPrompt` is poorly named. ..

Comment: .. `generalInfo` would be more accurate. 5) `addButtons()` - consider adding them (or the corresponding `Action` elements) to a `JToolBar` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one or more appropriate layout managers.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
 for more details

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class BookListUI {

    JLabel textPrompt = new JLabel("Welcome to the BookListApp, fellow bookworm. Start storing your books immediately!", JLabel.CENTER);

    public BookListUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 32, 32));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        frame.add(textPrompt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel menuPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(-1, 1));
        menuPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(32, 32, 0, 32));
        addButtons(menuPane);
        frame.add(menuPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("BookList Application");
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void addButtons(Container container) {
        container.add(new JButton("Finished books"));
        container.add(new JButton("Favorite books"));
        container.add(new JButton("Search by genre"));
        container.add(new JButton("Save all your books!"));
        container.add(new JButton("Load your BookList Application"));
        container.add(new JButton("Exit application"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new BookListUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use an absolute layout (panel.setLayout(null);) then you have to specify the bounds of the buttons to be visible:

```
button.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 30);
```

Comment: While not 'incorrect', this is a very poor way to layout a GUI and will result in many problems and lower the maintainability of the code. Until you understand how poor the advice is for cross-platform GUIs, please refrain from giving any more.

Comment: Yes, but he/she asked why the buttons were not visible, not asking for layout advice.

Comment: *"Yes, but.."* See [Is "Don't do it" a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/155831) Maybe if your answer had started, *"this is both one possibility, and also the worst way to do it"*. I might have up instead of down voted it.